# Codeigniter JQuery ajax post null value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm using jquery ajax to send data to controller but it returns null.

I just want to send single input text to controller using ajax.

```html
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sendOtp").click(function(e){
      console.log("working");
      e.preventDefault();
      //var mobileno = $("#mobileno").val();
      $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"<?php echo base_url()?>"+"index.php/welcome/generateOtp",
        data:  {mobileno: $("#mobileno").val()},
        dataType: "json",
        cache:false,
        success:function(response){
          console.log(response);
        },
        error: function ($data) {
          console.log(data);
        }
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

```
public function generateOtp(){

    $mobile = $this->input->post('mobileno');


    echo $mobile;

}
```

This is my html from where i have to send data

```
  <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mobileNo" id="mobileNo" placeholder="mobile">
        <br>
        <button class="btn" id="sendOtp">Send OTP</button>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: show your html as well

Comment: you are sending json data to server so set content type as json. otherwise just do normal data post

Comment: try with dataType: "json"

Comment: still null is return 
Object {name: null, value: "239567", expire: "86500"}

Comment: @TechBreak normal data post also returns null

Comment: Have you checked in the developer tools window, whether the actual mobile number is submitted? You can check this under XHR tab in developer tools.

Comment: when you say null what you mean? response null or some value as null? i see in response you get some values

Comment: if it is Ubuntu, it is case sensitive, mobileNo and mobileno will be treated differently.

Comment: @TechBreak plz avoid other values im sending mobile number in response i ask form mobile which im getting null

Comment: check if #mobileno gives you value and if not check for #mobileNo as it is the id of your input

Comment: @Rajesh: the case sensitivity of object keys has nothing to do with Ubuntu - it is a characteristic of JavaScript, and will be the same on all operating systems and browsers.

Comment: @halfer yes you are right here , I was working on windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is case sensitive, mobileNo and mobileno are different.

Comment: Done Thanks Rajesh

Comment: Anil, not just upvote, but also click the tick to mention it is accepted answer